# How can I split a group into subgroups of 5,000 contacts each?

Tags: groups

I saw an extension a while back that does this, but can't recall its name.  Can anyone tell me the name, or suggest another viable path to doing what I'm requesting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Split Group](https://civicrm.org/extensions/split-group) extension:

> This function takes a group of contacts, and splits it into several
>   new smaller groups, each with some maximum number of contacts. The
>   original group is left untouched.